# Php check if time string whole hour like "8:00am"

Tags: php, timestamp, time-series

I have series of time strings like "8:00am", "8:15am", "8:30am" I also have timestamps for these times as keys of the arrays where as times are values so array would be like this:

**Note:** Timestamps are dummy in this example

```
array(
144441415=>"8:00am", 
1444784744=>8:30am
...
.....
);
```

I would like to know if hour is whole hour for example "8:00am", "9:00am" are whole hours but "8:45am" or "9:30am" are not whole hours. I would like to filter whole hours from array as mentioned above. Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/date. Good luck.

Comment: Can you only use the string time value, or can you use the timestamp? If you can use the timestamp, you can check the minutes.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Rudie I can use either one how can I check minutes to know if timestamp is whole hour?

Comment: @ShehzadNizamani Just find the minutes with `date`, and compare it to `00`. `var_dump(date('s', '1447030800') == '00');` and `var_dump(date('s', '1447027205') == '00');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Rudie I was able to get whole hour from number of seconds, thank you for your hint, so I did something like this:

```
//Loop through each hour of the day by getting both key and value
foreach( $hours_of_day $timestamp=>$time_string )
{
    //If timestamp mod by number of seconds in hours is zero this means whole hour
    if( ($timestamp%3600) == 0 )
    {
        echo "Whole hour = $timestring<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$times = array(
    144441415=>"8:00am", 
    1444784744=>"8:30am",
    1444784745=>"8:45am",
    1444784746=>"9:00am",
    1444784747=>"10:00am",

);

foreach ($times as $time) {
    if (date("H:00:00", strtotime($time)) == date("H:i:00", strtotime($time))) {
        echo '<br>Whole Hour: '.$time;
    }
    else {
        echo '<br>Not Whole Hour: '. $time;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who may encounter this question, the best way to achieve this is the following:

```
define("BR", "<br />");
$data = array(
    144441415=>"8:00am", 
    1444784744=>"8:30am"
);

$tmp_dto; 
$tmp_mins;

foreach($data as $hour){
    $tmp_dto = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:iA", $hour);
    $tmp_mins = $tmp_dto->format("i");
    if($tmp_mins == "00"){
        echo "ROUND".BR;
    } 
    else{
        echo "NOT ROUND".BR;
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
ROUND
NOT ROUND
```